# WordPress group assignment from CiviCRM member signup not working

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page, roles

Edit: I was missing something basic. I was mapping role to role, not capability, and forgot to hit Save Settings on the main WordPress Member Sync plugin settings page.

Once I did that, and added the mappings *correctly*, it worked.

I must be missing something basic. Looked at similar questions and answers and went through the online docs, but have not found what I’m doing wrong / forgot to do. I’ve got a WordPress 5.9.2 / CiviCRM 5.43.2 set up with the Members and WordPress Member Sync plugins. WordPress has existing roles (call them A, B, C). CiviCRM has the same Membership Types defined.

I have a working (using dummy payment processor at least, this is in a sandbox environment) membership contribution page, which creates a new CiviCRM user, contribution, and WordPress user. But the WordPress user gets created with the default Subscriber role, and I want it to be the A/B/C role chosen at member signup on the contribution page.

I’ve defined the association rules in the member sync plugin, but I don’t understand how that maps the Membership Type A to the WordPress Role A. Is what I’m trying to do even possible? And what am I missing to make it work?

Thanks for any pointers / assistance here.

Michael

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Association Rules page?

Comment: Just added. I’ve also tried using Capabilities vs. Roses, clearing and re-adding, basically grasping at straws to see if anything sticks at this point. There was one point where I … oh, wait a second… might have just figured out what I did wrong…

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I didn’t see the ‘save settings’ button when I changed to Roles vs. Capabilities on the first screen.

Comment: Glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to save your settings in the member sync plugin to Roles before trying to add Roles association mappings.